# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.davidbriglio.foreground.ForegroundService@1d25633 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I was trying to build my ionic app in android studio and receive this error

```
2021-07-04 15:58:42.279 11626-11626/com.siloc.users E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.siloc.users, PID: 11626
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.davidbriglio.foreground.ForegroundService@1d25633 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4432)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:259)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2142)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7880)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object reference
        at com.davidbriglio.foreground.ForegroundService.onStartCommand(ForegroundService.java:16)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4414)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:259) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2142) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7880)
```

it seems like something is wrong with foreground services how i can fix this

it how i am using foreground service in my app

```
import { ForegroundService } from '@ionic-native/foreground-service';
ForegroundService.start('GPS Running', 'Background Service', 'drawable/fsicon');
```

AndroidMAnifest.xml

```
<application  >
<service android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.ForegroundService"/>
<service android:name="com.davidbriglio.foreground.ForegroundService" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
</application>
```

here is main.js file where i am using foregroundServices
`main.js`

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
import { ForegroundService } from '@ionic-native/foreground-service';
import { defineCustomElements } from '@ionic/pwa-elements/loader';

import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import StoragePlugin from 'vue-web-storage';


const { App, PushNotifications } = Plugins;

const routerEl = document.querySelector('ion-router');
console.log('Ro', routerEl)
document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev) => {
  ev.detail.register(-1, () => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    if (path === routerEl.root) {
      App.exitApp();
    }
  });
});
BackgroundMode.enable();
BackgroundMode.on('activate', () => {
  BackgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations();
  BackgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();


})

ForegroundService.start('GPS Running', 'Background Service', 'drawable/fsicon');

const app = createApp(AppMain)
  .use(IonicVue)
  .use(router)
  .use(RouterPrefetch)
  .use(StoragePlugin)

  .use(store);
defineCustomElements(window);
router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app');
});
```

here is main.js file where i am using foregroundServices

Comment: It clearly says you are trying to access on null intent in your service, share the code how you’re starting the service.

Comment: It was working fine suddenly starts giving error

Comment: Where do you construct or initialize the `ForegroundService`? It may be the way you have formatted your question but you don't appear to be initializing it.

Comment: this is the only place where i am using it in ionic

Comment: Can you show us the full code of the model where you are calling the `ForegroundService` API?

Comment: yes i added main.js file have look at it